# Can a RAWINPUT struct recieved from the OS have both a RI_MOUSE_LEFT_BUTTON_DOWN and RI_MOUSE_LEFT_BUTTON_UP?

Tags: windows, winapi, input

I'm trying to make an input library and I need to know if I have to account for the possibility that a person quickly clicking a mouse button can generate a RAWINPUT with both a RI_MOUSE_LEFT_BUTTON_DOWN and RI_MOUSE_LEFT_BUTTON_UP in it. The documentation seems to indicate that this might be possible, stating "The transition state of the mouse buttons. This member can be one or more of the following values."

EDIT:

I created a small program to feedback all the input packets from mouse and keyboard and a small autohotkey script to attempt to send Left button down and up at the same time, I was unable to create a packet with both left click up and down at it simultaneously.

Below is the C++ code and AHK script I used to test:

C++ code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

char mc[] = "mainclass";
int once = 1;
LRESULT CALLBACK mainproc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
    RAWINPUT fdsa;
    int size = 48;
    switch(message)
    {
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        case WM_INPUT:
            GetRawInputData((HRAWINPUT)lparam, RID_INPUT, &fdsa, &size, sizeof(RAWINPUTHEADER));
            if(fdsa.header.dwType == RIM_TYPEMOUSE)
            {
                cout << "mouse X = " << fdsa.data.mouse.lLastX << "\nmouse Y = " << fdsa.data.mouse.lLastY << "\nmouse buttons = " << fdsa.data.mouse.usButtonFlags << endl << endl;
            }
            else if(fdsa.header.dwType == RIM_TYPEKEYBOARD)
            {
                cout << "vkey = " << fdsa.data.keyboard.VKey << " & ";
                if((fdsa.data.keyboard.Flags&1)==1)
                    cout << "up\n\n";
                else
                    cout << "down\n\n";
            }
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wparam, lparam);
    }
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hthisinst, HINSTANCE hprevinst, LPSTR lpszArgument, int nCmdShow)
{
    HWND mainwin;
    MSG messages;
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    wc.hInstance = hthisinst;
    wc.lpszClassName = mc;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = mainproc;
    wc.style = CS_DBLCLKS;
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_BACKGROUND;
    if(!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
        return 0;
    mainwin = CreateWindowEx(0, mc, "main window", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 544, 375, HWND_DESKTOP, NULL, hthisinst, NULL);
    RAWINPUTDEVICE Rid[2];
    Rid[0].usUsagePage = 0x01;
    Rid[0].usUsage = 0x02;
    Rid[0].dwFlags = 0x100;
    Rid[0].hwndTarget = mainwin;
    Rid[1].usUsagePage = 0x01;
    Rid[1].usUsage = 0x06;
    Rid[1].dwFlags = 0x100;
    Rid[1].hwndTarget = mainwin;
    if(RegisterRawInputDevices(Rid, 2, sizeof(Rid[0])) == FALSE)
    {
        cout << "rawinput registration failed.\n";
        return 3;
    }
    while(GetMessage(&messages, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&messages);
        DispatchMessage(&messages);
    }
    return messages.wParam;
}
```

ahk script:

```
$f::
Sendinput {LButton Down}{LButton up}
Sendinput {LButton up}{LButton down}
return
```

I also tried

```
$f::
Sendinput {LButton Down}{RButton Down}
Sendinput {LButton up}{RButton up}
```

Unfortunately the second script didn't cause both keys to be pressed or released at the same time, which I can guarantee is possible because I've done it manually and verified it with the c++ program.

Comment: I don't see how the same button can be both up and down...

Comment: It doesn't seem likely you could have both. For one, how would you know which order the transition happened in?

Comment: Much of what the Raw Input API provides is very close to what the driver actually supplied. While it's unreasonable to expect both transition states to appear simultaneously, it might be possible to see this from a buggy driver.